# How to deploy a contract to the same address in testnet?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-debugging, hardhat-deploy, create2

My code for deploying a contract

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const CF = await ethers.getContractFactory('abc');
  const c = await CF.deploy();
  await c.deployed();
  console.log(`deployed: ${c.address}`);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
```

How to deploy it a 2nd and the consequetive times to the same address? At least, in the testnet.